# Why do global variables (list and int) not act the same?

Tags: python

1st case:

```
x = 5
def add(n):
    x += n
    return x

print(add(5))

local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

2nd case:

```
fi = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
def fibonacci(n):
    while len(fi) <= n:
        fi.append(fi[-1]+fi[-2])
    return fi[n]

print(fibonacci(10),fi)

55 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

both 'x' and 'fi' are outside the functions, why 'x' raise error but 'fi' not?

Comment: add `global x` inside the function and it will work too.

Comment: In the first case, you're writing to `x`, while in the second case you're only using the reference to `fi`. i.e. you never call something like `fi = whatever`.

Comment: @CerebralFart: Can you explain *why* `fi.append` is OK but `fi = `... is not?  That is, if `fi` can be found to invoke one of its methods, why can't it be assigned to?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh: The question isn't how to make it work, but *why*, when something similar, works without the need for `global`.

Comment: Instead of calling a method `fi.append(blah)` try to compare apples to apples by doing `fi += [blah]`. Assignments make things local by default

Comment: The keyword in the error is `assignment`. `x` is being reassigned, `fi` isn’t. Global variables can only be reassigned if declared global.